# Able to connect to Cloudant database, but cannot list contents from Bluemix Node.js app

Tags: node.js, api, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am using the CloudantDB service for a Bluemix app and I am able to connect to my database successfully but not list the contents. I get the error message:

```
Error: one of _all_dbs, _admin, server_admin is required for this request
```

Here is the code that causes this error message:

```
cloudant.db.list(function(err, data){
    if(err) return console.log('Error retrieving data: ' + err + '\n');
```

I am following the instructions from [here](https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant#Cloudantdblistcallback) to do this.

I have permissions set to 'Admin' for this user (so all permission checkboxes are enabled), so this user should be able to do anything with this database.

No idea what is going on. Any Cloudant people out there have an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code was using a single database API key to try and list all databases for a user. By changing `cloudant.db.list` to `databasename.list` (where 'databasename' is the name of the DB the API key was generated for), it worked fine. More info [here](https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant#dblistparams-callback).